# What happend the BindingFlags?

Tags: automapper

```
PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default);
```

I could only get the property that has at least one of these proteties . What do I have to do now?
Look at the other open topics

```
config.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic;
```

I found how to get the public ones using, but I still do not know how to get the inheritance and defaults. Can you help me?

Best regards.

Ramos

Comment: What framework are you targeting? BindingFlags shows up in quite a few target frameworks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.5.

Comment: That method exists in .NET 4.5 :shrug: